# Events in .NET OnClick button i want to show me some txt enterent in a previous textBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Since i am new to .NET programming i am trying to make same simple project just to learn and practice. 
But i am having probles with event handling. 
in my page i have to textBox(textBox1,textBox2) a Submit Button and a Label1.
what i want is that when i click on the submit button the label will show the text i enteret in textBox1 & textBox2.
Until now my code is as below:
For the onClick event

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = "You clicked the second button.";
    }
```

and

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    Enter Name:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
   </br></br>
</div>
    Enter Surname:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </br></br>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Results" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Solid" Width="157px"></asp:Label>

</form>
```

Comment: Show them where ? if in the label use it like this label1.text="Name: " + textbox1.text + " Surname: " + textbox2.text

Comment: get value of your textbox like this `string Text1Value=Text1.Value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are looking for is:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text + " " + TextBox2.Text;
    }
```

C# and especially WPF is very object oriented. So you should see everything as an object you can interact with.